# Invalid version string "4.x.x" + Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to install the "Asgardcms/Platform" package to Laravel 5.2.

I found error while installing this package

```
[RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not load package intervention/image in http://packagist.org: [Unexpec  
  tedValueException] Could not parse version constraint 4.x.x: Invalid versio  
  n string "4.x.x" 

 [UnexpectedValueException]                                                
  Could not parse version constraint 4.x.x: Invalid version string "4.x.x"
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: try with composer self-update command, It worked for me

Comment: When I use this command it's show me "[InvalidArgumentException] Command "self-update" is not defined."

Comment: Please have a look on this package versions : https://packagist.org/packages/asgardcms/platform 
They have not released version 4.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run Composer `composer self-update` it will resolved your problem

Comment: When I use this command it's show me "[InvalidArgumentException]             
  Command "self-update" is not defined."

Comment: have look https://github.com/hechoendrupal/DrupalConsole/issues/615, Hope the link will work for you.